# OpenLayers 3 prevent map interactions with autocomplete control

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I have a map with an autocomplete input control on it. I have given the control parent (`<div>`) the `class='ol-unselectable ol-control'` and I can type without the map interactions firing. However when I use the arrow keys to navigate down the autocomplete results the map pans. Any way to prevent this? Note that the autocomplete list is a child element of the `<div>`.

Comment: Try to set a negative `tabindex` in map DOM element.